# How to show the recently added section in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a table with one section and when I select any row, a new section gets added to the same table, and so on, the number of section to be added is not fixed i.e., two section can be added or three or four as it depends on the data coming from the server. My question is how can I show the recently added section when I reload the table?

Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reloading the table using `[tableView reloadData]`, use [scrollToRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a) method to scroll to a particular section/row. For example,

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] 
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                         animated:YES];
```

Comment: This function will consider the section in which I selected the row. not the added section

Comment: @Harsh Mehrotra, No. Its not like that. You can give any row/section number in that method. If there are currently 2 sections in your table and you are adding two more sections, then `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2] ` will move the table view to the third section(the is section 2).

Comment: Thanks Man! You guys rocks! :-) its working fine but from where did you find this method as it is not in the delegate methods to pass section as well?

Comment: @Harsh Mehrotra, Which section you want to pass?

Comment: I have passed the section but I am asking you where did you find this method?

Comment: That method is a UITableView instance method. You can find it in UITableView Class Reference. Click the link in *scrollToRowAtIndexPath:* text in my answer. It will take you to the page.

Answer (score 0):

**Update your Array when new data comes from server. and then reload the table.**

```
 - (void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
```

Comment: You didn't understood my question, I want to SHOW the recently added section when I reload the Table. If I simply reload the table then I will see the top section of the table. Well thanks for reply!